# How do I install Apache Tomcat 7?

Tags: apache2, tomcat

Troubleshooting with apache Tomcat 7 
steps should be followed ....

after downloading apache-Tomcat 7 //
open terminal go to that downloading file folder in which tar.gz file is still.

Untar the tar file

- `tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz`

  move a extracted directory of apache-Tomcat7 in current path
- `sudo mv Directory_Name(Extracted eg.apache-Tomcat 7.0.32)  /usr/local/Tomcat7`

to set environment variable for Tomcat7

- `sudo nano /usr/local/Tomcat7/bin/setenv.sh`

then Nano editor will open ..

```
 JAVA_HOME =/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
 export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

after hit ctrl+X to save file

- to set the role and username and password.

`sudo nano /usr/local/Tomcat7/conf/./tomcat-users.xml`

```
<role rolename="manager-gui" />
<role rolename="manager-script" />
<role rolename="manager-jmx" />
<role rolename="manager-status" />
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
```

Ctrl+X to save file

- If Port no confliction comes in a way then open file to change the port no.

`sudo nano /usr/local/Tomcat7/conf/./server.xml`

then change the connector port as you want....

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu, I've fixed the formatting for you, but it looks to me like you should have most of your question posted as an answer to your initial question.

Answer (score 5):

#### 11.10 or later

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

or the ***really*** easy way:

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Natty

Comment: @Mondain: Yup, tomcat7 first landed in oneiric.

Comment: Its certainly confusing for newbies. I just used the tar.gz from apache and it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat 7 is available for Precise and Oneiric https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat7

Backports for Natty are here:

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tomcat7-ubuntu/backports/ubuntu natty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tomcat7-ubuntu/backports/ubuntu natty main

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat generally doesn't need to be "installed" .  Just unzip it and go.   Most of the time there is no need for any configuration to get it going out-of-the-box.  Of course, once you start adding .war apps and other things, then configuration is needed, mostly in the server.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the installation description different from the above way of installation and the way it is described in the Tomcat Setup page(http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html) at the tomcat site under the title **Unix daemon**.

Comment: I asked the question because I install Tomcat as described here <http://www.coderanch.com/t/551474/Linux-UNIX/install-tomcat-Ubuntu-when-it> and I can't figure out what is the reason for different descriptions

Answer (score 0):

Good explaination is available at: http://clean-clouds.com/2011/10/19/install-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu/

For All Tomcat Versions.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.