# install tomcat on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: apt, package-management, tomcat, backport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Apache Tomcat 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37822/how-do-i-install-apache-tomcat-7)

I tried installing tomcat on 11.04 using `apt-get install tomcat7` but I get an error:

```
Unable to locate package tomcat7
```

I guess there's no tomcat7 package available for this distro. I tried enabling backports by adding the following to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

But I still get the same error.